# simple php Slim project errors

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver, slim

I've created a simple Slim microframework project using PHPStorm 8 on Windows 8.1 with WAMP Server installed. All WAMP Server settings are set by default.

I created a new project called `pr1`
I used `'Init Composer...'` and then added some dependencies like `slim/slim`, `slim/views`, `twig/twig`.

Then I tried to create a simple application just like a given example on main Slim page:

1. I've created file called `index.php` in my project folder
   index.php

code:

```
require 'app.php';
```

2. Then I've created file `app.php`

code

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/:name', function ($name) {
   echo "Hello, $name";
});

$app->run();
```

3. After this I tried to run my project in Chrome and there an error 404 occured.

[image: PHPStorm Error]

4. Then I tried to pass my name through url: `http://localhost:63342/pr1/wade` and there was PHPStorm error.

[image: phpstorm error]

5. After this steps I've tried to close PHPStorm and my project in browser:

[image: Slim error]

and it seemed like there's a typical Slim 404 error,but when I tried to pass my name through url again it gave me this error:

[image: wamp 404 error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All it was because Apachi doesn't know what to do with all browser requests. For this reason I've created a simple .htaccess file:

```
    RewriteEngine On

# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.
#
# RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

After this I needed to use rewrite_module in my WAMP settings.

It perfectly works with project when I open it in browser through the explorer.

And after this I set up my server like this:

[image: phpstorm server config]

And that allows me to preview all my changes through PHPStorm

Answer (score 1):

you need to include index.php for example http://localhost/pr1/index.php/test
to get rid of index.php use .htaccess or something equal based on your webserver

Comment: I've created a .htaccess file in the root of my project and now it works.